# Modelling dynamical systems with MATLAB/Mathematica

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

Recently I have been performing simulations on some dynamical system, where all the dynamical quantities are interdependent. To therefore simulate the dynamics I performed loops over small time steps dt<<1 and changed the quantities within each iteration. The simulations were done in respectively Mathematica and Matlab.
I got nice results but simulations could take quite long due to the slow iteration process. Generally I hear that one should avoid for loops like I have used, because they slow down the simulation greatly. On the other hand however I am clueless on how to do the simulations without iterations in small time steps. Therefore I ask you: For a dynamical system, where every quantity must be changed in ultra small time steps, what are then the possible methods for for simulating the dynamics.

Comment: stupid question: have you used the toolbox [**Simulink**](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink/)? Are you familiar with state-space models or at least simple transfer functions?

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward approach is to write the problem as a set of differential equations and use the ODE solving capabilities of either system.  Both MATLAB and Mathematica have advanced (and customizable) numerical differential equation solvers, and they both support special "events" in the differential equations that can't be expressed using a simple formula (e.g. the event of a ball bouncing back from the floor).

For Mathematica, first check out `NDSolve`, `WhenEvent` then later the [Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html).

From your description it sounds like you may be using a naive ODE solving method such as the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method).  Using a better numerical ODE solving technique can give significant effective speedups (by not forcing you to use "ultra small time steps").

If performance is paramount, consider re-implementing the simulation in a low-level language like C or C++, and possibly making it callable from Mathematica (LibraryLink) to allow easy data analysis and visualization.